# How do I use a custom AWS SDK with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I want to make a nodejs application that uses the AWS SDK. However, it only really needs to use S3, and I want the application to have a small filesize.

AWS has a [custom sdk builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) which should make a custom SDK with only the required packages. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, even when I select all of the services. How do I make a custom SDK that works with node?

I've tried using the `npm install aws-sdk`, and that works, but it's 40MB. I've also tried selecting all of the services in the service builder (only 3MB), but that doesn't work.

It always gives an error at this line:

```
var aws = require("./aws-sdk-2.462.0.min.js");
```

```
ReferenceError: AWS is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cwaugh/workspaces/meta-lambda/aws-sdk-2.462.0.min.js:7:30180)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cwaugh/workspaces/meta-lambda/handler.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the browser SDK. For Node you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3-node) module which only provides an S3 Client. That page has a clear example showing how to call putObject using this custom SDK.

There's many different individual modules for a variety of AWS services. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3).

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/)

You can install only the required packages as follows :

```
npm install @aws-sdk/client-s3
```

Use them as :

```
const {S3} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
```